# Finding users in the database owner role

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need a script which will list out all the users with the database owner permission for a specific database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971272/how-to-list-role-members-in-sql-server-2008-r2)

Below is your query to answer.

```
WITH RoleMembers (member_principal_id, role_principal_id)    
AS  
( 
  SELECT  
   rm1.member_principal_id,  
   rm1.role_principal_id      
  FROM sys.database_role_members rm1 (NOLOCK)  
   UNION ALL  
  SELECT 
   d.member_principal_id, 
   rm.role_principal_id      
  FROM sys.database_role_members rm (NOLOCK)   
   INNER JOIN RoleMembers AS d     
   ON rm.member_principal_id = d.role_principal_id  
)  
select distinct rp.name as database_role, mp.name as database_userl  
from RoleMembers drm  
  join sys.database_principals rp on (drm.role_principal_id = rp.principal_id)  
  join sys.database_principals mp on (drm.member_principal_id = mp.principal_id)  
  where rp.name = 'db_owner'  
order by rp.name
```